# how to save mutiple values in raiseevent() python function

Tags: python, pepper

In pepper Robo, I would like to pass username and password as values in raiseEvent() method in python to validate user login details.

i have added below function in working project

```
sesson.raiseEvent("eventname", username, password)

    function login()
    {
             alert('reached login details');
             var username = document.getElementById('txtusername').value;
             var password = document.getElementById('txtpassword').value;
             //alert(username);
             //alert(password);
             loginDetails(username,password);

    }


    function loginDetails(username,password){

                session.raiseEvent("loginreq", username,password);
                //window.location = 'paybympay.html?Language='+ LANGUAGE;
    }
```

.raiseEvent() has to accept multiple values such as username and password

```
tested in pepper robot did not accept the multiple values. how to achieve this.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the code you're showing is javascript on Pepper's tablet.

1) What you're doing looks very insecure. I would strongly advise against passing any raw user password as a value in ALMemory, *especially* for what seems to be a payment system.

2) A slightly better way of doing this would be to directly call a service of your own, e.g. from javascript you can call MyServiceOnPepper.handleLogin(username, password), for example see [the service-tabletpage example here](https://github.com/pepperhacking/robot-jumpstarter#template-service-tabletpage) for ways of doing that.

But I would not consider this secure enough for a user password, and would add encryption (for example, use RSA, and have your service publish a public key, and have the javascript use that to encrypt the password).

3) (it's also technically possible to pass a list as an ALMemory event, but using a dedicated service is cleaner and slightly more secure)